# How to have different tempos in a Logic Pro X session

Tags: mac, logic, tempo

Is there any way to change the tempo for a section of a piece in Logic Pro X. I'm fairly certain that I stumbled upon a way to do this before, but have been unable to replicate it. What I need to do is let's say that measures 1-40 are 110bpm, but then I need measures 41-52 to be 100bpm. How can I accomplish this in Logic Pro X?

Is there any easy way to do it, the way that time signatures can be changed? For instance, if I line up the selector to the measure where I want to change a time signature and I change the time signature, the time signature changes at that specified location. Is there a similar functionality for changing the tempo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by selecting from the top menu Edit->Tempo->Show Tempo List, and then click on the + symbol to add a new tempo change. The default starting point will be the location of your time bar, though you can change that and the expected tempo by double clicking on the values that appear listed in the Tempo List window.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! It's a shame it isn't as straight forward as changing time signatures, but it certainly did the trick. Thanks again.